# Is there a way to join the elements in an js array, but let the last separator be different?

Tags: javascript

What I want is something like `Array.join(separator)`, but which takes a second argument `Array.join(separator, beforeLastElement)`, so when I say `[foo, bar, baz].join(", ", " or")` I would get `"foo, bar or baz"`. I guess I could write a function that used `Array.slice` to separate out the last element, but is there some well known method that I could use instead?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**Updated answer for 2021!**

If the goal is to have a different separator between the penultimate and last elements such as "and" or "or", you can use [Intl.ListFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/ListFormat)

It does exactly that, and you get i18n for free.

It's supported in all major browsers except IE11.

Examples:

```js
const vehicles = ['Motorcycle', 'Bus', 'Car'];

const formatter = new Intl.ListFormat('en', { style: 'long', type: 'conjunction' });
console.log(formatter.format(vehicles));
// expected output: "Motorcycle, Bus, and Car"

const formatter2 = new Intl.ListFormat('de', { style: 'short', type: 'disjunction' });
console.log(formatter2.format(vehicles));
// expected output: "Motorcycle, Bus oder Car"
```

Comment: For anyone that is looking to use this without the Oxford Comma change the locale to `en-GB`

Comment: It may be well supported, but man that's an ugly API to have to use :(

Answer (score 109):

There's no predefined function, because it's quite simple.

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var str = a.slice(0, -1).join(',')+' or '+a.slice(-1);
```

There's also a specification problem for the main use case of such a function which is natural language formatting. For example if we were to use the Oxford comma logic we would have a different result than what you're looking for:

```
// make a list in the Oxford comma style (eg "a, b, c, and d")
// Examples with conjunction "and":
// ["a"] -> "a"
// ["a", "b"] -> "a and b"
// ["a", "b", "c"] -> "a, b, and c"
exports.oxford = function(arr, conjunction, ifempty){
    let l = arr.length;
    if (!l) return ifempty;
    if (l<2) return arr[0];
    if (l<3) return arr.join(` ${conjunction} `);
    arr = arr.slice();
    arr[l-1] = `${conjunction} ${arr[l-1]}`;
    return arr.join(", ");
}
```

So it seems better to let this problem in userland.

Comment: Note that this assumes `a.length > 1`. You should cover `a.length <= 1` as well

Comment: I'm not sure it should, I just wondered if there was, and if not if there was some agreed upon method of doing it. It would be silly writing something different than everyone else.

Comment: after the ' or ' maybe use `a[a.length - 1]`??

Comment: have an extra comma befor the conjuntion in the 3+ case

Comment: This covers the `a.length === 1` scenario: `a.slice(0,-1).join(', ') + (a.length > 1 ? " or " : '') + a.slice(-1)`

Answer (score 95):

May I suggest:

```
['tom', 'dick', 'harry'].join(', ').replace(/, ([^,]*)$/, ' and $1')
> "tom, dick and harry"
```

Comment: regex solution is great for this question and has the benefit of being able to support 0, 1 or more array elements. Great answer!

Comment: This works great, but with the downside of being quite unreadable to another developer, unless there's a comment above it. Tradeoffs.

Comment: This is a clean solution if you can be sure that the array elements do not contain commas. If they do, it won't work properly.
For example: `['England, UK', 'Bern, Switzerland','Asia']`
would translate to `"England and UK, Bern and Switzerland and Asia"`

Comment: It's not a tradeoff for people knowing regex. But there is indeed a (slight) tradeoff : the speed. Parsing a string (regex replace) is a """slow""" process added after concatenation is done.

Comment: @James your example is wrong because the regex only replaces the last occurence, so it would totaly work in your particular example, the comma would need to be in the last element of the array only. I do agree it's a risk tho, tho in my case in an array where values are controlled it is an elegant solution :)

Answer (score 26):

In-line solution using reduce:

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce((text, value, i, array) => text + (i < array.length - 1 ? ', ' : ' or ') + value);

=> "1, 2, 3, 4 or 5"
```

Answer (score 19):

No, this is specific enough that you will have to write a custom function. The good news is, as you said, once you use `Array.join` to take care of all the separators, the last one will be easy enough to update.

Answer (score 17):

Building off of @dystroy's answer:

```
function formatArray(arr){
    var outStr = "";
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        outStr = arr[0];
    } else if (arr.length === 2) {
        //joins all with "and" but no commas
        //example: "bob and sam"
        outStr = arr.join(' and ');
    } else if (arr.length > 2) {
        //joins all with commas, but last one gets ", and" (oxford comma!)
        //example: "bob, joe, and sam"
        outStr = arr.slice(0, -1).join(', ') + ', and ' + arr.slice(-1);
    }
    return outStr;
}
```

Example usages:

```
formatArray([]);                //""
formatArray(["a"]);             //"a"
formatArray(["a","b"]);         //"a and b"
formatArray(["a","b","c"]);     //"a, b, and c"
formatArray(["a","b","c","d"]); //"a, b, c, and d"
```

Comment: Great! However little bug on the line `outStr = arr.slice(0, -1).join(',') + ', and ' + arr.slice(-1);` Put a space after the comma within `join()`

Comment: @AndyB oops, yep you are right. I've added the space now.  Thanks!

Comment: another, more compact way would be:     `const formatArray = n => (n.length === 1) ? n[0] : (n.length === 2) ? n.join(" and ") : n.slice(0, -1).join(", ") + ", and " + n.slice(-1);`

Comment: @DerBobby but that doesn't work with  an empty array. Here my modified version: `const formatArray = n => n.length === 0 ? '' : n.length === 1 ? n[0] : n.length === 2 ? n.join(' and ') : n.slice(0, -1).join(', ') + ', and ' + n.slice(-1)`

Answer (score 7):

```
Array.prototype.join2 = function(all, last) {
    var arr = this.slice();                   //make a copy so we don't mess with the original
    var lastItem = arr.splice(-1);            //strip out the last element
    arr = arr.length ? [arr.join(all)] : [];  //make an array with the non-last elements joined with our 'all' string, or make an empty array
    arr.push(lastItem);                       //add last item back so we should have ["some string with first stuff split by 'all'", last item]; or we'll just have [lastItem] if there was only one item, or we'll have [] if there was nothing in the original array
    return arr.join(last);                    //now we join the array with 'last'
}

> [1,2,3,4].join2(', ', ' and ');
>> "1, 2, 3 and 4"
```

Answer (score 6):

Function version:

```
/* 
 * @param {Array.<string>} arr data array
 * @param {string} s1 regular separator
 * @param {string} s2 last separator
 */
function customJoin(arr, s1, s2) {
  return arr.slice(0,-1).join(s1).concat(arr.length > 1 ? s2 : '', arr.slice(-1));
}
```

```js
function customJoin(arr, s1, s2) {
  return arr.slice(0, -1).join(s1).concat(arr.length > 1 ? s2 : '', arr.slice(-1));
}

const arr1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
const arr2 = ['singleToken'];

console.log(customJoin(arr1, ',', ' and '));        // 'a,b,c and d'
console.log(customJoin(arr1, '::', ' and then::')); // 'a::b::c and then::d'
console.log(customJoin(arr2, ',', 'and '));         // 'singleToken'
```

Answer (score 4):

there is a package [join-array](https://www.npmjs.com/package/join-array)

```
const join = require('join-array');
const names = ['Rachel','Taylor','Julia','Robert','Jasmine','Lily','Madison'];
const config = {
  array: names,
  separator: ', ',
  last: ' and ',
  max: 4,
  maxMessage:(missed)=>`(${missed} more...)`
};
const list = join(config); //Rachel, Taylor, Julia, (3 more...) and Madison
```

Comment: npm package doesn't contain an ES5 bundle

Answer (score 4):

one-liner for nonempty arrays

```
arr.reduce((res, k, i) => [res, k].join(i  === arr.length - 1 ? ' or ' : ', '))
```

Comment: This is quadratic.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?
To me, it seems that [reduce](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.reduce) has a minimum complexity of `O(n)`, [join](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.join) has a complexity of `O(n)` and `length` is a stored property. Since the join is always performed on an array of 2 elements, the resulting complexity of the two should be `O(n)`. Isn't it?

Comment: `res` is a string whose length is O(n), so that's an O(n) operation inside a loop repeated `n` times--O(nn). In other words, the complexity of `join` isn't quite so simple as the number of elements. If one of those elements keeps getting longer, bound to O(n), that's no longer ignorable. Another constant time penalty here is repeated allocations that are quickly discarded, `[]` and the string.

Answer (score 3):

Though its a late answer, adding some approaches.

**Method 1**: Using Array.splice() add the `last delimiter` before last element and join and remove the last two `,`.

```js
function join(arr,last)
{
    if(!Array.isArray(arr)) throw "Passed value is not of array type.";
    last = last || ' and '; //set 'and' as default
    
    (arr.length>1 && arr.splice(-1,0,last));
    arr = arr.join().split("");
    arr[arr.lastIndexOf(",")]="";
    arr[arr.lastIndexOf(",")]="";
    return arr.join("");
}

console.log( join([1]) ); //single valued array
console.log( join([1,2]) ); //double valued array
console.log( join([1,2,3]) ); //more than 2 values array,
console.log( join([1,2,3],' or ') ); //with custom last delimiter
console.log( join("name") ); //Non-array type
```

**Method 2**: Using Array.reduce() to construct the string by traversing each element.

```js
function join(arr,last)
{
    if(!Array.isArray(arr)) throw "Passed value is not of array type.";
    last=last||' and ';
    
    return arr.reduce(function(acc,value,index){
        if(arr.length<2) return arr.join();
        return acc + (index>=arr.length-2 ? index>arr.length-2 ? value : value+last : value+",");
    },"");
}

console.log( join([1]) ); //single valued array
console.log( join([1,2]) ); //double valued array
console.log( join([1,2,3]) ); //more than 2 values array,
console.log( join([1,2,3,4],' or ') ); //with custom last delimiter
console.log( join("name") ); //Non-array type
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the simplest solution is:

```
['1', '2', '3'].reduce((previous, current, index, array) => {
    if (index === array.length - 1) {
        return previous + ' & ' + current;
    } else {
        return previous + ', ' + current;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getValuesfromArray(strArray) {
  let endString = "";

  if (strArray.length > 1) {
    const lastEntry = strArray.pop();
    endString = strArray.join(", ") + " or " + lastEntry;
  }
  else {
    endString = strArray.toString();
  }

  return endString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using destructuration:

```js
const { log } = console;

const formatList = list => {
    const [last = "", ...rest] = [...list].reverse();
    return rest.length
       ? [last, rest.reverse().join(", ")].reverse().join(" and ")
       : last;
};

log(formatList([1, 2, 3, 4]));
log(formatList(["Me", "Myself", "I"]));
log(formatList(["", ""]));
log(formatList([42]));
log(formatList([]));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Denys Séguret's oxford style join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15069646/11347983), but without last comma:

```js
function readableJoin(arr, conjunction = 'and', ifEmpty = '') {
  const length = arr.length;

  switch (length) {
    case 0:
      return ifEmpty;
    case 1:
      return arr[0];
    case 2:
      return arr.join(` ${conjunction} `);
    default:
      const arrCopy = arr.slice(0, -2);
      arrCopy.push(`${arr[length - 2]} ${conjunction} ${arr[length - 1]}`);
      return arrCopy.join(', ');
  }
}

readableJoin(['one', 'two', 'three']); // 'one, two and three'
```